# undefined reference to 'cocos2d::network::HttpClient::send(cocos2d::network::HttpRequest*)'

Tags: android, c++, networking, cocos2d-x

I'm developing a game that stores data on server in cocos2d-x 3.2 in eclipse c++ for android.

In **.h** file I include network file `#include "network/HttpClient.h"`.

In **.cpp** file I wrote following code.

```
HttpRequest *request = new network::HttpRequest();
request->setUrl("My Url");
request->setResponseCallback(CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onHttpRequestCompleted, this));
cocos2d::network::HttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);
```

But on `cocos2d::network::HttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);` generate `undefined reference to 'cocos2d::network::HttpClient::send(cocos2d::network::HttpRequest*)'` this error.

I search it on cocos forum too but i don't get solution of my error.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you .cpp file sees the include correctly? Looking at [ref.](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_use_CCHttpClient) it seems your code is correct.

Comment: Yes I'm 100% sure, because when i start typing any word of class it shows me whole name automatically.

Comment: Careful with that conclusion, the IDE might deceive you.

Comment: I search on different forums and google, it is not IDE deceive

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still interested in this but all you need to do is add the libnetwork.tbd to your project. For me I used XCode so I just goto Target and then to the Build Phases and add libnetwork.tbd in the "Link Binary with Libraries" section. Then I am able to import "network/HttpClient.h" and using namespace cocos2d::network.